# How to select linked without delimiting?

Tags: linked-data

When I use <kbd>L</kbd> to select linked vertices, there's a delimit option in the sidebar that I can't deselect. I want to select all linked vertices without a delimiter. How do I do that?

**EDIT:** This wasn't possible in v2.78. Selecting linked vertices without selecting a delimiter has been implemented in v2.79b!

Comment: One option must be enabled. I don't see the normal option making a difference, while material only effects face and edge select modes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 2.79b at least, you can select multiple delimiters or deselect delimiters by shift LMB on the appropriate button.  With no delimiters enabled, it will only limit select linked by mesh connections.